# botframeworkv4 - List of available Channel IDs

Tags: c#, botframework

While exploring the new preview of the `botframeworkv4` in C#, I came across a case where I need to do a specific action for a certain channel. In `botframeworkv3`, I used to access all the channels string names using [`ChannelIds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.channelids?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) but I can't find it here.

I know that I can directly write `"facebook"` for example, but using the provided list prevents any typos and improves readability.

Therefore, what is the equivalent of `ChannelIds` in `botframeworkv4`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ChannelIds` has been replaced with `Channels` in the C# V4 SDK and is available under `Microsoft.Bot.Connector`.

Checking for a specific channel can be done easily, for example:

```
var isEmail = turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == Channels.Email;
```

Use Nicholas R's answer if you need to add custom channels (or example Android, iOS) to the list.

Answer (score 6):

### 2019-2020 Response:

The Channel list is available in `Channels` object in Microsoft.Bot.Connector namespace:

https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/Channels.cs

### 2018 Response:

`ChannelId` is still an existing property in Activity object in v4, see sources:

https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Schema/IActivity.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Channel this activity is associated with
/// </summary>
string ChannelId { get; set; }
```

The list of channelId values is still available in v4 through `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Classic`:

https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Classic/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Classic/ConnectorEx/IChannelCapability.cs

```
public sealed class ChannelIds
{
    public const string Facebook = "facebook";
    public const string Skype = "skype";
    public const string Msteams = "msteams";
    public const string Telegram = "telegram";
    public const string Kik = "kik";
    public const string Email = "email";
    public const string Slack = "slack";
    public const string Groupme = "groupme";
    public const string Sms = "sms";
    public const string Emulator = "emulator";
    public const string Directline = "directline";
    public const string Webchat = "webchat";
    public const string Console = "console";
    public const string Cortana = "cortana";
}
```

Side note: you can simply add your own list:

```
public enum ChannelEnum
{
    emulator,
    facebook,
    skype,
    webchat,
    directline
    // ...
}
```

and use `activity.ChannelId == ChannelEnum.webchat.ToString()`

Comment: Yes, but I am talking about `ChannelIds` (Note the s). Updated the question to include a link to the v3 documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.channelids?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)

Comment: Ok you are talking about the list reference, sorry. I updated my answer to point to `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Classic`

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. One more question: should I keep using those? (I saw 'Classic' in the namespace, that's why I'm asking)

Comment: Honestly? If you don't need the `Classic` namespace, which is pointing to v3 things, I would say that you could just keep your enum of Channels and you're done (that's what we do sometimes even in v3)

Comment: Ok thanks! That's what I'll do then. Voted the comment Up so that other viewers would notice the note.

Comment: Added more details in the answer for this possibility

Comment: List moved to https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/Channels.cs

Comment: thanks @JustinHarris I finally made an edit of the response to be more up-to-date